# Cannot read temporary tables with IDataReader

Tags: c#, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, temp-tables, datareader, temporary

Is it possible to read temporary tables using IDataReader?
I am connecting to Snowflake through ODBC.

```
//e.g.
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMPTABLE1 (ID INT);

sting query = "SELECT * FROM DB1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'LOCAL TEMPORARY' OR TABLE_TYPE = 'GLOBAL TEMPORARY' OR TABLE_TYPE = 'TEMPORARY' OR TABLE_TYPE = 'VOLATILE'";
using (IDataReader reader = Connection.Query(query, null))
{
    while (reader.Read()) {...}
}
```

Reader is empty, did I make mistake somewhere, or there is some technical limitations on this one?

Answer (score 2):

You are creating the temporary table and THEN you are connecting with IDataReader afterwards. Thats why you don't see the table - its another session and temporary tables only exist within the session in which they were created.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-temp-transient.html#temporary-tables

Comment: Connection, as well as session are the same at the time of creating temporary table and when i query it with IDataReader, I also explicitly check session id after reader = Connection.Query(query, null) and it's still the same...so I do not have any idea what could be the issue...

Answer (score 1):

Temporary tables are visible in context of the same session.

[Optional Parameters](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html#optional-parameters):

> ```
> TEMP[ORARY] | LOCAL TEMP[ORARY] | GLOBAL TEMP[ORARY] | VOLATILE
> ```
>
> Specifies that the table is temporary. A temporary table persists **only for the duration of the user session in which it was created** and **is not visible to other users.**

---

Alternative apporach is the usage of [SHOW TABLES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-tables.html)(all in context of the same session):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp(i INT);

SHOW TABLES;

SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) WHERE "kind" = 'TEMPORARY';
```

[image]